# Recorrer un objeto y obtener su contenido

Tags: jsonarray

[image: Quiero recorrer el objeto que despliego con los datos: alias, pais, edad, etc... Lo ago pero el resultado es el que muestra unicamente el 0: sin ningun datos.]

El recorrido lo logro con la funcion:

```
transformEmployeeData2(array) {
    var obj = {};
    var final = [];
    var arrayJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayJson.length; i++) {
        obj = {};  // <-- Se limpia la variable objeto para que no almacene más de una referencia
        var general = array[i];
        for (var n = 0; n < general.length; n++) {
            var data = general[n];
            var first = data.shift();
            var last = data.pop();
            obj[first] = last;
        }
    final.push(obj);
    }
    console.log(final);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para recorrer el `Array` lo haría de esta manera:

```
array.forEach(elemento => {
  console.log(elemento.fields.alias)
  console.log(elemento.fields.edad)
  console.log(elemento.fields.email)
  console.log(elemento.model)
  console.log(elemento.pk)
})
```

Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: Funciono para recorrer mi array!!